# Linq Except considering only one property

Tags: c#, linq

I have two lists of object.

```
List<object1> obj1 = new List<object1>();

List<object2> obj2 = new List<object2>();
```

I want to do this:

```
obj2 = obj2.Except(obj1).ToList();
```

However, by reading other questions similar to mine, I understand that this doesn't work unless I override Equals.

I do not want to do that, but both obj2 and obj1 have a string property that is sufficient to see whether they are equal. If `obj2.StringProperty` is equivalent to `obj1.StringProperty` then the two can be considered equal.

Is there any way I can use Except, but by using only the string property to compare?

Comment: What is object1, are object1 and 2 instances of the same class?

Comment: https://morelinq.github.io/2.0/ref/api/html/M_MoreLinq_MoreEnumerable_ExceptBy__2.htm

Answer (score 63, accepted):

The `Except` method requires that the two collection types involved have the same element type.  In this case the element types are different (`object1` and `object2`) hence `Except` isn't really an option.  A better method to use here is `Where`

```
obj2 = obj2
  .Where(x => !obj1.Any(y => y.StringProperty == x.StringProperty))
  .ToList();
```

Comment: I think join is also a good option when trying to use `Except` on different types.

Comment: To be even prettier: .Where(x => obj1.All(y => y.StringProperty != x.StringProperty))

Answer (score 16):

In **.Net 6** you can use [`.ExceptBy()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.exceptby?view=net-6.0) from `System.Linq`.

If your classes contain the following properties:

```
public class Object1
{
    public string String { get; set; }
}

public class Object2
{
    public string String { get; set; }
}
```

`.ExceptBy()` can be used like this to compare the two string properties:

```csharp
var objects1 = new List<Object1>();
var objects2 = new List<Object2>();

// Populate lists

objects2 = objects2
    .ExceptBy(
        objects1.Select(obj1 => obj1.String)
        obj2 => obj2.String) // selecting the String property of Object2 for comparison
    .ToList();
```

Example fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/WJ1KIQ).

---

(Using `.ExceptBy()` has also been suggested by @mjwills in their comment, via MoreLinq.)